# How to manage a CPU intensive process on a server

Tags: python, performance, signal-processing

I need to run a CPU- and memory-heavy Python script (analyzing and altering a lengthy WAV file) as a background process on my web server (a VPS), between HTTP requests.

The script takes up to 20 seconds to run and I am concerned about the performance on my server. Is there a good approach to either lower the priority of the process, periodically cede control to the OS, or otherwise protect the performance of my modest server?

Answer (score 7):

Assuming it's a UNIX server, you could use the [nice command](http://www.builderau.com.au/program/linux/print.htm?TYPE=story&AT=339286637-339028299t-320002022c) to lower its priority.  That should do the trick.

Comment: Python conveniently provides os.nice(...)

Answer (score 5):

You can use [cpulimit](http://cpulimit.sourceforge.net/) on a linux based server. It will allow you to limit the CPU usage (specify the limit as a percentage) even of scripts that have already started running, and its usage is pretty straightforward.

It's available on the Debian repository, so you can install it easily using aptitude:

```
apt-get install cpulimit
```

Typical ways to use `cpulimit` includes:

```
# To limit CPU usage to 75% of program called foo:
cpulimit -e foo -l 75

# To limit CPU usage to 50% of program with pid = 1582
cpulimit -p 1582 -l 50
```